# Retrieve parent/parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Three models: Provider, Course and Call

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :calls, through: :courses

end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :calls, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :facilities, through: :calls

    belongs_to :provider

end

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :provider
    has_one :facility

end
```

I know I can do `provider.calls` and have all calls of all that provider's courses. Call 133 is in the results. However, if I make `Call.find(133).provider` it returns `nil`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you can, what is the question?

Comment: That's the question. It's not working for me. Giving me nil if I do call.provider. However, if I do provider.calls, that call is in the result.

Comment: @potashin, answering 'yes' means that you are answering a question. I guess that's my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have `through: :courses` for `provider.calls` relation - it searches for courses of that provider and gets calls from these.

The other way - simple `belongs_to` expects provider_id to be set on call, which is not (because of many-to-many relation above), it cannot have `through`, so:

- use `call.course.provider` (and may be cache it in provider_id, if you need)